# Merge columns from different statements into one variable

Tags: azure, powershell, networking, merge, virtual-machine

I'm preparing my VM report for the client consisting of this information:

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -status

$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        "Environment" = $_.Tags.Environment
        "Application" = $_.Tags.Application
        "Decommission Date" = $_.Tags.Decomission
        "OS Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        "Data Disks Total Size" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB | Measure -Sum).Sum
        "Data Disks Amount" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks | Measure ).Count
        "Managed OS Disk" = ($_.StorageProfile.OSDisk.ManagedDisk | Measure).Count
        "Managed Data Disks" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.ManagedDisk | Measure).Count
        "Powerstate" = $_.PowerState
    }
}
```

After this statement an output is saved as CSV file:

```
$vmOutput | sort "Environment", "VM Type", "VM Profile", "Application" | export-csv VMReport.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

I want to add a private IP addresses per VM to this report. Only solution I found to get such information is through this statement:

```
foreach($nic in $nics)
{
    $vm = $vms | where-object -Property Id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $prv =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress
    Write-Output "$($vm.Name) : $prv"
}
```

How can I parse information about IP's per VM into $vmOutput variable before the export-csv command in order to include both statement outputs into one file?

Comment: guess you can get all the properties like you get the $vm.name in the second code snippet that you have mentioned.

Comment: I know, but how can I add it to the $vmOutput later ? By some kind of join statement?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Define $vmOutput, add a placeholder field(like `"Private IP" =""` ).

When loop the ips, you can add the `vm name` and `ip address` to a hashtable.

At last, you can iterate the $vmOutput, if the `vm name` matches that in hashtable, then you can use the `ip address` stored in hashtable to replace the one in $vmOutput.

Sample code like below, and works at my side:

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Status

 $vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object {
 [PSCustomObject]@{
 "VM Name" = $_.name
 "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
 "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
 "Environment" = $_.Tags.Environment
 "Application" = $_.Tags.Application
 "Decommission Date" = $_.Tags.Decomission
 "OS Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
 "Data Disks Total Size" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB | Measure -Sum).Sum
 "Data Disks Amount" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks | Measure ).Count
 "Managed OS Disk" = ($_.StorageProfile.OSDisk.ManagedDisk | Measure).Count
 "Managed Data Disks" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.ManagedDisk | Measure).Count
 "Powerstate" = $_.PowerState
 "Private IP" ="" #Add the placeholder
 }
 }


 $vms_temp = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx"
 $nics = get-azurermnetworkinterface -ResourceGroupName "xxx"| where VirtualMachine -NE $null
 $ips =@{} #define a hashtable to store vm name and it's private ip


 foreach($nic in $nics){
 $vm = $vms_temp | Where-Object -Property id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
 $prv = $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress
 $ips.Add($vm.Name,$prv)
 }


 foreach($vm in $vmOutput)
 {

 #if vm name matches, you can use the ip address stored in hashtable to replace the one in $vmOutput
 if($ips.ContainsKey($vm."VM Name"))
 {
 $vm."Private IP"=$ips[$vm."VM Name"]

 }

 }

 $vmOutput | sort "Environment", "VM Type", "VM Profile", "Application" | export-csv d:\VMReport.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved an issue perfectly.