# Merge Storage Account Name and SKU with VM Name in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I want to add StorageAccountName and its SKU to my report, this is the code I'm having now:

```
VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -Status

 $vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object {
 [PSCustomObject]@{
 "VM Name" = $_.name
 "Private IP" =""
 "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
 "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
 "Environment" = $_.Tags.Environment
 "Application" = $_.Tags.Application
 "Decommission Date" = $_.Tags.Decomission
 "OS Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
 "Data Disks Total Size" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB | Measure -Sum).Sum
 "Data Disks Amount" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks | Measure ).Count
 "Managed OS Disk" = ($_.StorageProfile.OSDisk.ManagedDisk | Measure).Count
 "Managed Data Disks" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.ManagedDisk | Measure).Count
 "Powerstate" = $_.PowerState
 }
 }

 $nics = get-azurermnetworkinterface | where VirtualMachine -NE $null
 $ips =@{}

 foreach($nic in $nics){
 $vm = $VMs | Where-Object -Property id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
 $prv = $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress
 $ips.Add($vm.Name,$prv)
 }

 foreach($vm in $vmOutput)
 {
 if($ips.ContainsKey($vm."VM Name"))
 {
 $vm."Private IP"=$ips[$vm."VM Name"]
 }
 }

 $vmOutput | sort "Environment", "VM Type", "VM Profile", "Application" | export-csv VMReport.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

I tried to do it more less the same way [IP addresses were implemented into this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310382/merge-columns-from-different-statements-into-one-variable), but it's much harder than I expected, as Get-AzureRmStorageAccount cmdlet doesn't store VirtualMachine.Id property like Get-AzureRMNetworkInterface cmdlet does.

Any ideas how can I merge it into one table? Is there any key upon which I can join both information? What I want to achieve is to add StorageAccountName and SKUName columns into the $vmOutput table.

Update:

```
$sat =@{}

$OutFile = "..."

#part1

foreach ($vmdetails in $VMs)
{
$ResourceGroupName=$vmdetails.ResourceGroupName
$VMName=$vmdetails.name
$storage=$vmdetails.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.Uri
$DataDiks=$vmdetails.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name
$ss=$storage.split('/')[2]

$OSStorageAccountName=$ss.split('.')[0]
$DiskType="OSDisk"
$StroageAccountLocation=($StroageAccDetail | where  {$_.StorageAccountName -eq $OSStorageAccountName }).location
$StorageAccountType=($StroageAccDetail | where  {$_.StorageAccountName -eq $OSStorageAccountName }).AccountType
"$sub,$ResourceGroupName,$VMName,$DataDiks,$DiskType,$OSStorageAccountName" | Out-File -FilePath $OutFile -Append

$vmdatadisks=$vmdetails.StorageProfile.DataDisks

if($vmdatadisks -ne $null){
foreach($vmDatadsik in $vmdatadisks)
{
$vmDatadsikss=$vmDatadsik.vhd.uri
$DiskType="DataDisk"
$ss=$vmDatadsikss.split('/')[2]
$DataDiks=$vmDatadsik.Name
$dataStorageAccountName=$ss.split('.')[0]
"$sub,$ResourceGroupName,$VMName,$DataDiks,$DiskType,$OSStorageAccountName" | Out-File -FilePath $OutFile -Append
}
}
}

#part2

$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "..." -Name "..."
$storageAccountName = $VMs.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.Uri.Split("/")[2].Split(".")[0]
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName "..."
```

Comment: you are not calling `get-azstorageaccount` anywhere, so its hard to understand what you want to do exactly

Comment: So far I manage to write that code (shown as "Updated" in first post):

1st part of code binds Storage Account Name with VM's for both OS and Data type disks into a file, but this loop doesn't include SKUName sadly and it saves into file rather than a variable, which would be more preferable option IMO. 

2nd part gets Storage Account Name and its SKUName for specific VM in specific RG. 

What I want to achieve is to join SA Name and SKUName with all VMs by VMs.Name, so I can add it to the main report, like I did with Private IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding you.

Assume the sku you refer to the account storage's sku, you can also add placeholders in the $vmOutput for SA Name and SKUName.

```
 $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -Status  

 $vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object {
 [PSCustomObject]@{
 "VM Name" = $_.name
 "ResourceGroupName" =$_.ResourceGroupName #you must include this parameter
 "storage" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.Uri #you must include this parameter
 #your other property
 #add placeholder for SA Name and SKUName like below
 "StorageAccountName" =""
 "StorageAccountSKUName" =""
}
}
```

Then, iterate all the vms in $vmoutput, and find the related storage account and sku, then add value to the $vmoutput:

```
foreach($v in $vmOutput){
$resourceGroups = $v.ResourceGroupName
$storage=$v.storage

if($storage -ne $null)
{
$ss=$storage.split('/')[2]
$OSStorageAccountName=$ss.split('.')[0]

$s1 = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroups -StorageAccountName $OSStorageAccountName

#add the value to $vmoutput
$v.StorageAccountName =$OSStorageAccountName
$v.StorageAccountSKUName=$s1.Sku.name
}
else
{
$v.StorageAccountName ="no value"
$v.StorageAccountSKUName="no value"
}
}
```

Comment: That is almost exactly what I wanted to achieve, thank you very much! But it doesn't include data about Premium SSD, but only Standard LRS or GRS storage.

Comment: I assume it's because premium storage is directly attached to VM, not through Storage Account, so I just changed "no value" into Premium SSD.